# .NET dynamically adding attributes to element with XmlSerializer

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization, vb.net-2010

I am creating an XML with serialization and I have a problem when I need to create attributes dynamically to an element. I am adding elements of dates that have a price data in them. My class structure for the XML looks like this:

```
 <XmlRoot(ElementName:="root")>
    Public Class DateXML
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="date")> _
        Public Property Dates As List(Of DatePrice)
    End Class

    Public Class DatePrice
        <XmlAttribute("value")> _
        Public Property DateValue As String
        <XmlElement("price")> _
        Public Property Price As String
    End Class
```

The XML will then look like this for example:

```
<root>
    <date value="2013-01-01">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value="2013-01-02">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value="2013-01-03">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value="2013-01-04">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value="2013-01-08">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value="2013-01-12">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
</root>
```

My problem is with a requirement for the XML. If I have multiple date values with the same price I should put them in one node using `value1="2013-01-01" value2="2013-01-02"` etc. Additionally if the dates follow each other I should use `from="" to=""` attributes and I am allowed to mix these attributes. The goal is to create as few of the date nodes as possible using attributes. So the example above should be something like this:

```
<root>
    <date from="2013-01-01" to="2013-01-04">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
    <date value1="2013-01-08" value2="2013-01-12">
        <price>100.00</price>
    </date>
</root>
```

How should I create my DatePrice class to accomplish this requirement? I am getting the data per date from the database. I could add the from and to attributes as a properties to the class but is it possible to add attributes dynamically for the value1, value2...?

EDIT:

I'm a bit closer now after discovering how to serialize an dictionary. Here is what I have tried:

```
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="root")>
Public Class XmlObject
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="element")> _
    Public Property element As String 
    Public Property elementAttributes As ValueAttributes
End Class

Public Class ValueAttributes
    Public Property values As SerializableDictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

Dictionary class that implements IXmlSerializable:

```
Public Class SerializableDictionary(Of AttributeName, AttributeValue)
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Implements IXmlSerializable

    Public Function GetSchema() As System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.GetSchema
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub ReadXml(reader As System.Xml.XmlReader) Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml 
        If reader.HasAttributes Then
            While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()

                Dim key As String = reader.Name
                Dim value As String = reader.Value
                Me.Add(key, value)
            End While

            reader.MoveToElement()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteXml(writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter) Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml     
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Me
            writer.WriteAttributeString(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Using these I'll get an XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <element>the element value</element>
  <elementAttributes>
    <values value1="1" value2="2" value3="3" />
  </elementAttributes>
</root>
```

Now I just would need to somehow figure how to move the attributes to the `element` and not write the `elementAttributes` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question as I have a solution that I think I can live with for now or at least going to give it a try to see if it will be enough. So to create the  nodes and add the attributes dynamically to them I have created a class that looks like this:

```
Public Class DateElement
    Implements IXmlSerializable

    Public Property DateValueAttributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Property Price As String

    Public Function GetSchema() As System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.GetSchema
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub ReadXml(reader As System.Xml.XmlReader) Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml
        If reader.HasAttributes Then
            DateValueAttributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            While reader.MoveToNextAttribute()
                DateValueAttributes.Add(reader.Name, reader.Value)
            End While

            reader.MoveToElement()
        End If

        Dim wasEmpty As Boolean = reader.IsEmptyElement
        reader.Read()

        If wasEmpty Then
            Return
        End If

        While reader.NodeType <> System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement
            reader.ReadStartElement("price")
            Price = reader.ReadString()
            reader.ReadEndElement()
        End While

        reader.ReadEndElement()

    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteXml(writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter) Implements System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In Me.DateValueAttributes
            writer.WriteAttributeString(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        Next

        If Price IsNot Nothing Then
            writer.WriteStartElement("price")
            writer.WriteString(Price)
            writer.WriteEndElement()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

I can use this class in my xml object for example:

```
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="root")>
Public Class XmlObject
    <XmlElement("date")>
    Public Property [element] As DateElement
End Class
```

And then creating the object in code for example like this:

```
Dim xml As New XmlObject()
        xml.element = New DateElement()
        xml.element.DateValueAttributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        xml.element.DateValueAttributes.Add("value1", "2013-01-01")
        xml.element.DateValueAttributes.Add("value2", "2013-01-02")
        xml.element.DateValueAttributes.Add("value3", "2013-01-03")
        xml.element.Price = "100.00"
```

Will give a result XML that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <date value1="2013-01-01" value2="2013-01-02" value3="2013-01-03">
    <price>100.00</price>
  </date>
</root>
```

I think I am close enough now so I can work with this. If anyone have any ideas I would be more than happy to hear them.